# pg_basebackup for one database only

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-12

I have a server that is hosting 9 databases at once. Only 1 of them is important.

I do this query to find their cumulative size :

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( SUM(pg_database_size(datname))::bigint ) As human_size
    ,  SUM( pg_database_size(datname) )::bigint   As raw_size
    , pg_size_pretty( (SUM(pg_database_size(datname) ) - pg_database_size(current_database() ) )::bigint ) aS h_without_current
    FROM pg_database;
```

The result :

```
human_size |   raw_size   | without_current
-----------+--------------+-----------------
332 GB     | 194080676140 | 209 MB
```

Apparently, the important one database, is not that big, only around 120 GB.

I do not want to back up the whole databases. Only this particular one database is the most important one out of all.

What backup method is suitable? I want to do pg_basebackup for this. But I do not see any option to limit to only 1 database.

Need your advice

Thanks

Comment: You can't. pg_basebackup is not intended for that. Use pg_dump

Comment: So, I have there is no other option for me except pg_dump ?

Comment: Actually, I have a spare server that is acting like a shadow of this server. But the "replication" to this server is manual (data are copied and pasted manually if I want to back them up). I know this is not a good idea. What I actually want is pg_basebackup with PITR. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: From the manual: pg_basebackup — take a base backup of a PostgreSQL cluster. And: pg_dump — extract a PostgreSQL database into a script file or other archive file. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/reference-client.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . If I use `pg_dump`, how can I clean up the archived WALs? I get the notion that if I use `pg_dump` then I dont have to turn on the `archive_mode` and I just can delete the archive Wals straight away.